# Draw route map between two locations via another location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I don't know about Google maps API much and I am just learning now. With the example explained [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel), I am able to draw map between two locations. But I am just curious to know whether it is possible to include `via` location or not.. Any help on this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using `waypoints` like below

```
 var request = {
   origin: "Mumbai, India",
   destination: "Pune, India",
   waypoints: [{ location: "Via point address", stopover: true}],
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };
```

Thanks